# django-admin.py only prints help

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django-admin.py prints help only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107196/django-admin-py-prints-help-only)

Trying to learn Django, and every time I run the `django-admin.py` script all it does is print the help.  What's the problem?

```
N:\Code\djtest>django-admin.py startproject helloworld
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
(...)

N:\Code\djtest>django-admin.py help startproject
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
(...)
```

If I run `python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject blahblah` that does work, though it's onerous.

- Related questions that don't help:

  - [django-admin.py is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123688/django-admin-py-is-not-working-properly)
    The script is being run with the proper Python interpreter version and the file type is associated correctly (tacked on a `import sys; print sys.version` into the script)
  - [django-admin.py startproject is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681216/django-admin-py-startproject-is-not-working) The script exists, the envvar doesn't exist, not using a virtual environment

Comment: If your run on Windows, did you set your %Path% environment variable? with (for example)  'C:\Python27;C:\Python27\scripts;' variables in it?

Comment: @Geoff, both paths are in the PATH envvar