# django-admin.py prints help only

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.3.1

I followed the online tutorial and tried to use "django-admin.py startproject mysite".

But I　always receive this:

```
D:\Code\djtest>django-admin.py startproject mysite
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
(...)
```

What is going on?

Comment: Giving the correct path to mysite? Is it in the same dir as djangoadmin?

Comment: @Sid No, not in the same dir. But I think it does not matter. Right? I can choose any dir?

Comment: If you want create your project from any where in your system for that django-admin.py should be on your system path if you installed Django via its setup.py utility.

Comment: @himanshu Yes. It is in my system path.

Comment: @ChongWang, try `python full_path_to/django-admin.py startproject mysite` - this is an odd issue I've seen a few times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299241/cant-open-file-django-admin-py-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory where the script is apparently being found but not accepting arguments.

Comment: Try giving the full path to the project dir even though it's in your PATH.

Comment: @YujiTomita Yes, Your advice works! Thanks!

Comment: @Sid Could you post it as answer? It'll be much clearer for people with the same issue. I'll gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem and solved it using this tool: 
[FileTypesManager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html)

The problem is that django-admin.py is not receiving the correct arguments from the command line. I did a test by hacking a couple of lines into the front of the admin script to display the number of arguments and what they were before it did anything else. The hack:

```
    #!d:\python27\python.exe
    from django.core import management
    import sys
    print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
    print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
       management.execute_from_command_line()
```

When you run django-admin.py you will see that there is only 1 argument ever being passed. Which is not correct.

As suggested in several forums, I tried both of the following at the command line, and both looked spot on:

```
    assoc .py            -->  .py=Python.File
    ftype Python.File    -->  Python.File="D:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*   //Correct
```

I then looked in the registry and the values looked good as well.

However, when I ran [FileTypesManager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html), (it's free) it showed something different. The command-line was set as:

```
   "D:\Python27\python.exe" "%1"      //Wrong!
```

I have no idea why, but as soon as I updated this value it all worked flawlessly.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I can confirm that this solved the same problem on Win 7 x64 for me.

Comment: yes, I can too confirm. The .py file was showing wrong entry. I then modifies it using the fileTypeManger software and then it worked correctly. However when i go to regedit.exe in win7 and look for .py it does not show the command line entry. Not sure what could be issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. Setting the file type association in FileTypesManager on Windows 8 (adding `%*` basically) worked!

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows 7, update the registry entry at:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command
```

to have the value:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

(modify the above value if you have installed python in a different location)

Answer (score 1):

In regedit under
*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command*
modify the entry from

```
"<your drive>:\Python<version>\python.exe" "%1"
```

to

```
"<your drive>:\Python<version>\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

I had the same problem and I resolved it this way.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still has this problem, there is no need to mess with your registry. Here is the answer you need: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10732170/1585863)

Basically it's:

> Add 'python' before django-admin.py (or add full path to python.exe).
>
> C:\Shekhar\djangoWorld>python c:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite

Which means you are running the django-admin.py as an arguement to the python interpreter; as against running it as a stand-alone script, in which case it doesn't actually get the supplied arguements for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the full path to the project dir even though it's in your PATH

Answer (score 0):

1. Open regedit
2. go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
3. change to "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

It works for me.