# django-admin.py returns nothing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am a total newbie when it comes to django. However I have experience with python, I know how to install modules etc. I work on Win7 x64 with Python 2.7

Here is what I did:

1. Made sure Python environment variable is Set in %PATH%
2. installed django with `pip install Django` and checked afterwards if it installed (1.5.4)
3. added C:\Python27\Scripts to the environment variables (django-admin.py is there)
4. restarted cmd
5. enter `django-admin.py help` - no Error nothing, jumps to next line
6. enter `django-admin.py startproject mysite` - no Error, no Folder created, jumps to next line
7. enter `django-admin.py gsfögjsdfüoisudhihdsf` - no Error, nothing jumps to next line
8. did a `pip uninstall Django` and reinstalled it with `pip install Django` and tried started again at point 1

So now I have no idea what could be wrong. I even checked if the `from django.core import management` in the django-admin.py works - it does.

Any ideas?

Edit: Solved it by changing the .py associations. If you still encounter an error (like I did) go [How to edit file associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107196/django-admin-py-prints-help-only)

Comment: What happens if you prefix any of those commands with `python`?

Comment: If I do a `cd Python27/Scripts` and execute the command from there it works as expected. So maybe there is something messed up with the environment variables?

Comment: Okay I got it! My .py-Files got somehow associated to _pythonw.exe_ not to _python.exe_, which might have caused the problems.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as resolved, but usually in Windows, you must run `python` with those commands as command-line arguments.