# django-admin.py startproject mysite is not doing anything

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

It worked when I did the poll tutorial in linux, but I'm doing it again in Windows 7, and it does nothing.

I already set the environmental variables, and set the file association to my `python27.exe`

When I run `django-admin.py` startproject mysite from the DOS command prompt, it executes, but it's showing me all the information (Like the options, etc) as though I typed the help option instead. It's not actually creating project files in my directory. I appreciate the help.

also, I tried the solution found here (it appears to be the exact same problem).
It did not work

[django-admin.py is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123688/django-admin-py-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.

Never having worked with Django before but having worked with Python 2.7 a fair bit, all on a windows 7 platform. I downloaded the latest version of Django and unpacked it on my desktop.

After mucking around a bit managed to get it to install itself. I found could not just follow the tutorial thats provided in the docs googled the problem and found this thread, now I was able to get it to work by doing the following things,

I work with a dos command window open. I navigate to the root of where I want the project file to be set up. I then ensure that the django_admin file has been editted as per wynston's instructions and then typed the following.

```
python c:\location of django_admin.py startproject projectname
```

and it executed beautifully.

*Thanks to wynston for the edit to the django_admin.py file.

Comment: This worked for me, everything else I've tried hasn't thus far.

Comment: Doens't Wynstons answer deserve a +1, then?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `python27 django-admin.py startproject mysite` from the command line,maybe a different (older) python.exe executes the `django-admin.py` file. If there's a program associated to the `.py` files, things mixes up, and your  `path` environment variable doesn't matter.

I suggest you to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). When you use it, you should put the python.exe before every `.py` file you want to run, because the install of python will associate .py files to the installed python.exe, and will use that, whatever is in your path. :(

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line of django-admin.py `#!/usr/bin/env python` to for example 
`#!D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe` (Where you install your python.exe,that's my directory), it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `python django-admin.py startproject mysite`. That worked for me some time ago when I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple in Windows:

1-Go to C: \ Python34 \ Scripts

2-Right click on django-admin.py

3-Select open with

4-Select default program

5-Select Laucher Python for Windows (Console)

6- Run the command in CMD Windows `python django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Answer (score 0):

Great answers. But unfortunately it did not work for me. This is how I solved it

1. Opened `django_admin.py` as @wynston said. But the path at first line was already showing `#!C:\` correctly. So did not had to change it
2. I had to put `"..."` around `django-admin.py` address. Navigated to the project directory in `cmd.exe` and ran this

   python "C:\Users\ ......\Scripts\django-admin.py" startproject projectname

It worked only with the quotation marks. I am using Anaconda Python 2.7 64 bit, on Windows 7, 64 bit. Hope it helps