# django-admin.py does nothing except showing all available options

Tags: python, django

When I want to start new Django project this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, nothing is happenning, except showing all available options.

Where is the problem?

Comment: what happens when you execute `django-admin.py` by referencing it using its absolute path on your filesystem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5601612/538284 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/3237555/538284, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10732170/538284, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8989825/538284 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/9252970/538284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `python` explicitly:

```
python django-admin.py startproject....
```

If still getting the same problem, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14936708/236195