# django-admin.py startapp myproject does not create settings.py

Tags: django-admin, python-2.7, django-1.3

I have Python2.7 and Django 1.3.1, running on windows 7 32bit

When I type 'python django-admin.py startapp myproject', the folder that is created looks like:

mysite/
    **init**.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py

instead of

mysite/
    **init**.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py

Now the reason I have to type in 'python django-admin.py startapp myproject' instead of just 'django-admin.py startapp myproject' is because .py files are not properly associated with python, a solution was suggested in this thread:
[django-admin.py is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123688/django-admin-py-is-not-working-properly)

I tried it but I could get the proper association for some reason.
I also made sure django-admin.py should be opened with python.exe file through Properties.
Finally both django-admin.py and python.exe are added to system path as configured in Computer ->properties>advanced->environmental variables.

So a bit out of ideas here...

Comment: P.S. this command worked before and am not sure what changed. In addition, other python commands such as 'python manage.py runserver' works even though when I type in 'assoc .py' into the command prompt, I get 'File association not found for extensions .py'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `startproject` instead of `startapp`.

Check out the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination

Comment: wow... I am an idiot     http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/000/554/facepalm.jpg

Answer (score 11):

1 `django-admin.py  startproject myproject`
creates a project and files like `init.py`, `manage.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py`
2 `python manage.py startapp appname`
creates a app inside my project and files like `init.py`, `models.py`, `tests.py`, `views.py`

Answer (score 4):

> django-admin.py startproject myproject

creates a project and files like

- **__init__.py**              *use files as an global modules*
- **manage.py**                *to manage project like, Syncdb, migrate,
  startserver*
- **settings.py**              *Contains The Project Settings*
- **urls.py**                  *Contains Project URL,you can include the
  app url file*

> python manage.py startapp appname

creates a app inside my project and files like

- **__init__.py**               *use files as an global modules*
- **models.py**                 *You can write your model classes here*
- **tests.py**                  *To write test cases*
- **views.py**                  *App URLs*